# conduct linear regressions {y = mx + c} for many small subsets of a large dataset, then append each value of m, c and r2 to the relevant subsets

Tags: python, loops, subset, linear-regression

Despite researching heavily (and learning a lot so far) I must be missing something basic with what I'm trying to do.
Or maybe it's a tricky problem, I wouldn't know, I'm a beginner!
Either way, I'm stuck and would love some help, please.

I have a collection of linear regressions to calculate, each for a subset (up to ~20 rows) of a single .csv comprised of thousands of rows.

For some context: The data are greyscaled values extracted from regions of images of a scientific sample, and in-situ chemical compositions from those same regions of that sample.
There is nothing fancy about the calibration: all I need is a linear regression between 2 columns of data: 'comp' and 'greyscale'. **BUT** I need these individual calibrations later to apply to *each* of the original images, and so for the linear expression `y = mx + c`, I need one m, c, and r2 for each subset of the dataset.

This is where I'm stuck! How do I do this on subsets of the data?
I have tried groups and dicts of data frames, but can't seem to crack the critical part of introducing each subset to a loop so each part comes out the other end as a list of unique values of m c and r2.
I have read that splitting and generating numerous csvs, for example, is not efficient, and I don't want to get into bad habits at the start of my python journey... but of course, I just want something that works, at least to begin with.

Here are some toy data (I read in the CSV but you can just zip these lists together if you want to recreate):

```
    ID = ['E01A_A1', 'E01A_A1', 'E01A_A1', 'E04B_B2', 'E04B_B2', 'E04B_B2']
    comp = [60, 72, 81, 62, 74, 83]
    greyscale = [200, 180, 160, 201, 178, 162]
    df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(ID, comp, greyscale)),
    columns =['ID', 'comp', 'greyscale'])
    df
```

The regression code is this:

```
    x = df['comp']
    y = df['greyscale']
    
    def linear_regression(x, y):     
        N = len(x)
        x_mean = x.mean()
        y_mean = y.mean()
    
        B1_num = ((x - x_mean) * (y - y_mean)).sum()
        B1_den = ((x - x_mean)**2).sum()
        B1 = B1_num / B1_den
    
        B0 = y_mean - (B1*x_mean)
    
        reg_line = 'y = {} + {}β'.format(B0, round(B1, 3))
    
        return (B0, B1, reg_line)
    
    N = len(x)
    x_mean = x.mean()
    y_mean = y.mean()

    B1_num = ((x - x_mean) * (y - y_mean)).sum()
    B1_den = ((x - x_mean)**2).sum()
    B1 = B1_num / B1_den

    def corr_coef(x, y):
        N = len(x)
    
        num = (N * (x*y).sum()) - (x.sum() * y.sum())
        den = np.sqrt((N * (x**2).sum() - x.sum()**2) * (N * (y**2).sum() - y.sum()**2))
        R = num / den
        return R

    B0, B1, reg_line = linear_regression(x, y)
    R = corr_coef(x, y)

    R = (corr_coef(x, y))
    r2 = R**2
    m = B1
    c = B0

    print(m)
    print(c)
    print(r2)
```

Any ideas and help are greatly appreciated!

Comment: That's one of these questions I could never find an answer for no matter where I looked. I believe Julia programming language is the future. You can easily parallelize your code and do not have to worry about loop performance.

Comment: Thanks Tarik, that's good to know! For now, is chopping the csv into pieces, saving them, then iterating the loop over them a workable option do you think? And... If so, how would I do that? Lol

Comment: I would use the groupby function and iterate over the groups.

Comment: Thanks Tarik, I thought this would work and I also tried putting each group into a dict. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious in setting up the iteration and dealing with the results.
e.g:
for i in dict_of_groups:
    x = ['comp']
    y = ['greyscale']
    print(c)
gives 
313.286
313.286
which is telling me something is iterating, but that it's writing the last calculated value over every instance.
I feel like I'm really close on an answer, could you teach me how to do this iterate each group and assign to that group part please?

Comment: I think there is an apply method or something on the generated groups.

Comment: Another solution is to use set_index, specifying the columns upon which you base your groups. You can the simply use the loc function to get the rows group by group